# is there possible to create pipeline from GitHub to AWS EKS deployments on Git actions?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, amazon-eks

I want to create a cicd pipeline from github to aws eks.
Is there possible to create pipeline from GitHub to AWS EKS deployments on Git actions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes its possible you need to use some kind of CI/CD tool (Jenkins/Gitlab/AWS Native services) in between to automate this whole process.

Flow would be something like

Developer commit changes --> Trigger CI/CD pipeline --> Build Docker image --> Push it to ECR -- Deploy latest image to EKS using (Kubectl or Helm charts)

Please refer :
https://www.eksworkshop.com/intermediate/260_weave_flux/ this has example for end to end implementation.

https://www.weave.works/blog/gitops-with-github-actions-eks
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/git-push-deploy-app-eks-gitkube/

Comment: I have configured flux for deployment, but now flux pod is get `CrashLoopBackOff` and restarting hence I can not do the deployment, any comments on this.

Comment: I have tried and above issue has been solved not trying to push images to ECR but getting `no basic auth credentials` in GitHub actions.